# Webcam as Ambient Light Sensor in Windows 7

Tags: webcam

Windows 7 introduces an Adaptive Brightness service that requires an Ambient Light Sensor doodad to work.  Is there software that turns a webcam into a (periodic) ALS that is compatible with the ambient brightness service?

Comment: There’s plenty on eBay for <$10, but most of them are for Apple laptops (though they can probably be adapted for general use).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is certainly some ways to achieve this using Autohotkey as is discussed here : [Using a webcam as an ambient light sensor](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic60687.html)

But [BackLight Unit coNTRoL](http://sven.killig.de/BLUntrl/)  should work :)