# How can I find a light sensor to adapt my monitor's brightness to the room?

Tags: windows-7, brightness

Where can I find a standalone light sensor that updates the brightness of my screen to match the ambient light level in realtime for Windows 7?  My monitor does not have a sensor.  I had the idea there was such a thing, but all I can find is for laptops or Macs.

Comment: There’s plenty of them on eBay, but most of them are for Apple laptops (though they can likely be adapted for general use).

Comment: Any idea how I could adapt one?

Comment: Nope. I don’t have one of the sensors. The problem is that new-fangled peripherals like ambient-light-sensors and other fancy toys that new versions of Windows support (like multi-touch screens on desktops) just aren’t that common yet, so you’ll really have to put time, money, and effort into find something that works. `:-(`

Answer (score 4):

Check this before buying somethings, *May be* it's a solution if there's no such sensors built-in your PC...

[Webcam as Ambient Light Sensor in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/284706/webcam-as-ambient-light-sensor-in-windows-7)

Hope this help. Let us know. :)

Comment: Cool idea, it does work, but I'd rather have it update the brightness more smoothly and not flash the recording light on my webcam.  Just me.